# Running subprocess in iOS?

Tags: ios, subprocess

Is it possible to launch a new sub-process in iOS? (from regular application)
If possible, how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "process"? (A thread of execution, or some form of external code?)

Comment: @middaparka A program execution in separated memory. Not a thread. Threads can be made with pthread os NSThread :)

Comment: I don't believe there's any form of [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) equivalent if that's the sort of thing you're after. (Bearing in mind the sandbox approach that's prevalent on iOS, this shouldn't be a surprise.)

Comment: @middaparka Thanks for `NSTask` and additional description :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it may be possible with jailbreak apps, the SDK does not allow that. You are only allowed your own application's process. It can operate in the background (for a limited amount of time) and/or have however many threads of its own as you say, but they all have to belong to that one process.